# Trying to run archlinux image of docker-compose but its just exits with code 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, archlinux

I am trying to start archlinux image and later  add volumes so I can test my scripts on configuring Arch Linux. But I am stuck with starting the compose. If I have restart: always it just restarts all the time when I comment it out, then it gives me the exited with code 0.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  arch:
    image: archlinux/base
    # restart: always
```

I start compose with

```
$docker-compose up
```

and the output is

```
Creating network "docker-compose_default" with the default driver
Creating docker-compose_arch_1 ... done
Attaching to docker-compose_arch_1
docker-compose_arch_1 exited with code 0
```

What might be missing?

Any help is much appreciated. I have being stuck with this problem for quite a while.

Comment: Docker container is not a virtual machine that will run doing nothing. Container is a process, if the command exits, the container will go down as well.

Comment: You might be better off thinking of a Docker container as a wrapper around a single process, that happens to bring some fraction of a Linux distribution along with it.  The process ran to completion, so the container exited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base image you are using at the moment [executes `/usr/bin/bash` as a default command](http://archlinux%20dockerfile/) which requires allocation of a tty to keep running (or you will have to change the command to any long running task).

See what happens with docker itself in first place.

Starting a container interactively works as expected:

```
$ docker run -it --rm archlinux/base
[root@6642c519e328 /]# more /etc/issue 
Arch Linux \r (\l)

[root@6642c519e328 /]# exit
```

Now let's try to run a container in the background:

```
$ docker run -d --name testarch archlinux/base
915ff11b0c93bd795eb62d37cd2d9928638560d9accfb2e5ba061b3ef19c0235
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
$ # Hoho, it's not running
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
915ff11b0c93        archlinux/base                                      "/usr/bin/bash"         8 seconds ago       Exited (0) 7 seconds ago                       testarch
$ docker rm testarch 
testarch
```

If we do the same with a tty allocation:

```
$ docker run -d --tty --name testarch archlinux/base
d160a3d7e18c3d094f47577b448a11808eb30ce7ba8fad4cde882818f248f207
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d160a3d7e18c        archlinux/base      "/usr/bin/bash"     5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds                            testarch
$ # Tada ! It runs, we can now attach to it.
$ docker exec -it testarch bash
[root@d160a3d7e18c /]# more /etc/issue
Arch Linux \r (\l)

[root@d160a3d7e18c /]# exit
$ docker rm -f testarch
```

Now back to your `docker-compose.yml`. In your current test phase, you need to allocate a tty (that you will be able to drop later if you cmd/entry-point does not require one anymore).

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  arch:
    image: archlinux/base
    tty: true
```

For time being, the bash command is not sending anything in the container log. I will start in detached mode so the command returns once the container is started and I can use the same terminal (launch a second terminal if you still want to to run docker-compose in foreground mode)

```
$ pwd
/tmp/slack_test
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "slack_test_default" with the default driver
Creating slack_test_arch_1 ... done
$ docker-compose exec arch bash
[root@10f138d98782 /]# more /etc/issue 
Arch Linux \r (\l)

[root@10f138d98782 /]# exit
exit
$ docker-compose down
Stopping slack_test_arch_1 ... done
Removing slack_test_arch_1 ... done
Removing network slack_test_default
$
```

Answer (score 1):

its because archlinux has `CMD[/usr/bin/bash]` [https://github.com/archlinux/archlinux-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile](http://Archlinux%20Dockerfile) which means you have to specify any long running task to let the container running otherwise it will exit e.g you can pass argument to bash such as while loop to keep it running.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  arch:
    image: archlinux/base
    command:
     - "while(true); do sleep 5; done"
```